# Adding minutes to current time that is in input form

Tags: javascript, html, time

I have this current time code in an input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="sum()">
  Current Time: <input type='time' value='now' readonly disabled>
  <script src='scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script id="rendered-js">
  $(function () {
    var d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = d.getMinutes();
    if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
    if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
    $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function () {
      $(this).attr({ 'value': h + ':' + m });
    });
  });
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I add minutes from another input field? 
Example:  2:00 pm + 00:30 minutes = 2:30pm

It has to be in an input field please

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the `setMinutes` property.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes

But you'll need to maintain a reference to the original date, recalculate, then update the DOM. Something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  var d = new Date(),
  h = d.getHours(),
  m = d.getMinutes();
  if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
  if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr({ 'value': h + ':' + m });
    // attach this event to the input controlling the minutes: 
    $(this).addEventListener('change', e => {
      // set the minutes
      d.setMinutes(e.target.value)
      // update the minutes variable
      m = d.getMinutes()
      // update the HTML attribute to reflect the new value
      $(this).attr({ 'value': h + ':' + m });
    })
  });
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry but I am not that advanced, I do not know what you mean exactly. I found that code online to display time in an input, and I want another input where a user can put the time, and a third input for the answer.